# azure mobile service custom api script http request timeout

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I implemented exports.get = function(request,response) of a custom api on a mobile service of azure. I download 5 thousands records from the rest service and then i prepare the json for the output. The problem is that the time of downloading of all records is too long, for that script exceeds the default timeout of 30 secs. I was thinking if there is a way to increase the timeout of the response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can have a timeout greater than 30 seconds, as I have encountered this problem myself with azure custom APIs. According to this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894042.aspx, Table operations are limited to 30 seconds, but it's not clear if that applies to custom apis, but it certainly appears to be.

What I would recommend is to implement pagination and return a limited number of records at a time. Your parameters should include the the start index and amount of records to return, and your response should include how many records in total so you can determine how many records to fetch with each request.